# How to close an open window of eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have opened another window in eclipse by mistake using **Window->New Window...**
I don't find where to close it.
do you know how?
EDIT:
I am using linux FVWM so I don't have the close button.

Thanks.

Comment: are you serious? There's a close button on it like normal window, why don't use that?

Comment: @Nishant, this is also proving to be problematic when using xming.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default it has a `Close button mark with [X]` at top. By clicking on it or pressing `ALT + F4` you can close it Or you can also exit it from File menu. `File-->Exit`. But this option will exit all the windows of eclipse means all eclipse instance will be closed. So better if you go with First option.

Hope this helps.

***Edit:***

To close a window you could use somthing like this in linux fvmw:

```
AddToFunc close_window
+ I ThisWindow ($0) Close

Key F11 W SCM close_window
```

This would close the current focused window when you hit `ALT-CTRL-SHIFT-F11`.

Also take a look at this: [Window options in FVWM](http://www.helpdesk.umd.edu/topics/computer_labs/all/3584/)

Comment: In the link you provided in "Windows operation" section "close" command.

Comment: No, its good I just gave the pointer so anyone look in the link will find what he need.

Answer (score 5):

Two routes I know of :
- (CTRL + F6) to list all open windows and navigate between them
- Select the 'offender'
- (CTRL + F4) to close it.

or

- (CTRL + SHIFT + F4) to close all the windows

Comment: It will show editor windows only not all the eclipse windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use awesome-wm, and i have the same problem. I solve it using the shortcut to close current window. On awesome-wm it's Mod4-Shift-c.

Hope that help.