# How to close a "Shaded Area" window in Counterclockwise

Tags: eclipse, clojure, counterclockwise

I have a strange window in Counterclockwise. When I mouse over it in the restore bar the tool-tip calls it "Shaded Area". I can minimize it, peek at it, and restore it, but I cannot see how to close it! [A similar eclipse question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4812868/575530) suggests `ALT-F4`, which closes the whole of Counterclockwise, or `ALT-CTRL-SHIFT-F11`, which does nothing.

I'll include screenshots just to be clear that there is no close button mark with `[X]`.

Peek:

[image: first screenshot]

Restored:

[image: second screenshot]

How do I close this window?

Answer (score 0):

I have a fix.

Drag some of the code windows into the shaded area and then close the remaining ones. The Shaded area now grows to fill the usual code area and behaves as normal.